# Why would my zone controller be displaying error: AC voltage insufficient?

Tags: hvac

Our AC unit was new with our house and is only 7 years old. We have a split zone system controlled by a Honeywell HZ322. Today we had no AC so I started looking at possible issues. When I got to the controller test, the AC test clicks a few times, on the controller, and says "AC voltage insufficient". The heat and fan will test fine.

If there is enough voltage for the fan and heat, how is it that only the AC is out? Is there a fuse for each area of the unit. One fuse each for fan, AC, heat, and so on? I am only seeing one.

I am familiar with electronics. Multi-meters and such so if you have any of those ideas feel free to post them.

Comment: Haul out the meter and check the voltage. Either it''s normal and the AC needs repair, or it really is low and the unit is correctly protecting itself. (Possibly the concern is risk of burning out the compressor motor, but that's just an educated guess.) If it's low, next question is whether the problem is in your house (fix the wiring) or not (complain to the electric company, but this _us_ summer and brownouts sometimes happen).

Comment: An install that new should have a disconnect outside, next to the condenser, which may be tripped.

Comment: It has been off all night so I tried it this morning and .. it came on! Can't explain that one. Would a frozen coil cause this to happen? We have a tech coming today. I will post results once he it done.

Answer (score 2):

The tech seems to think the HZ322 is going bad. The good news is they are not terribly expensive and fairly easy to program.

So since it started working he could not say what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the transformer that powers the zone board (HZ322). I had the same issue. Transformer was old and it was losing power. I replaced it and got the issue fixed.